# Expression for "getting 'aha' moment after long time of failing explanations"

Tags: expressions

I'd like to recall that there's an expression along the lines of "*coin dropping down*" used to described the moment when an explainee finally reaches the verge of grasping a concept after the explainer tediously has gone through the pains of presenting a multitude of examples, approaches and pedagogical tricks.

Googling it gave me no hits and searching on SO for "*coin*" resulted in way too many. None of that was of relevance, though.

Can I use the following phrase in correct English to describe that I'm trying to explain a bit more because I see that the subject is about to get the "*aha moment*"?

> I was about to give up but I felt that the coin was about to drop down.

Comment: See [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5685/24489)

Comment: @StoneyB I believe that's the correct answer. Post it as so, please, and I'll check it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression is [The Penny Drops](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/280900.html). You could write:

> I was about to give up but I felt that the penny was about to drop.

Comment: It's unusual that the idiom is used to anticipate a mental "unblocking". It's normally said *after* the person has understood the problem e.g., *I was about to give up, when the penny finally dropped*

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variant of

> "... when it finally clicked."

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is an [epiphany](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epiphany):

> a moment in which you suddenly see or understand something in a new or
>   very clear way

In your phrase:

> I was about to give up but I felt that an epiphany was about to
>   happen.

Comment: I'd say that *epiphany* is a more profound realization of a deeper truth. I was looking rather for a more common, down-to-earth expression. It seems to that *aha moment* and *epiphany* are quite far apart. What's your take on it? I'm thinking *oh, I **am** in love with her* is an epiphany while *oh, **tupac** not two-pack* is rather a penny dropping...